# Bing-Spellcheck Api doesn't work for languages other than English (en-US)

Tags: c#, bing-api

**The error**

When I call the Api with mkt or language set to `da`, the response list is empty no matter what I do.

**What have I done until now**

**Nuget package and tried with English (worked)**

I've added the service to my Azure subscription and tried the c# code for it for English:

```
   var text = "he wil be their in 5 minut";
   var result = client.SpellCheckerWithHttpMessagesAsync(text: text, mode: "proof", acceptLanguage: "en-US").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

and I get 3 results back which is expected:

[image: results on English]

**Nuget (c#) with danish returns empty**

Now I change the language to Danish as it is in the [supported languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-spell-check/bing-spell-check-supported-languages)  with Language code `da`.

```
var text = "De er pa dansk";
var result = client.SpellCheckerWithHttpMessagesAsync(text: text, mode: "proof", /*acceptLanguage: "da",*/ market:"da").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I've tried with both market and acceptLanguage set to "da" (both separated and together) but it didn't work. and the results is empty.

[image: danish results]

I have also tried the Api using postman but the same thing happened

**Api call directly for English (worked)**

[image: English]

**Api call directly for English (not working)**

[image]
I also receive `BingAPIs-Market →da-DK` in the response headers back.

### Update

As Ronak has suggested, I've changed mode to `spell` but it mostly doesn't catch a thing.

If I run it with bil gate in Danish market it returns 1 token so at least I know it is checking something
[image: bil gate danish]

But when I write a misspelled Danish sentence it returns nothing.
The original sentence is this:

> Fra på søndag kan der komme ekstra meget fart på cykelstierne

which I have changed to

> ra på søndag ka der komme ekssra meget fart pa cykelstierne

```
Fra => ra
kan => ka
ekstra =>ekssra
på=> pa
```

Url encoded to

> ra%20pa%20sondag%20ka%20der%20komme%20ekssra%20meget%20fart%20på%20cykelstierne

[image: wrong danish]
[image: url encoded wrong danish]

### Update 2

It seems that there is a limitation or something on the number of the words. When I try the sentence as Ronak mentioned `"ra%20pa%20sondag%20ka%20der%20komme%20ekssra%20meget%20fart"` I get the results back, but when I add one more word (like `ra%20pa%20sondag%20ka%20der%20komme%20ekssra%20meget%20fart%20pa`), the response will be empty again.
[image: partial sentence]
[image: adding 1 more word]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mode=proof` is only supported for the `en-us` market.

Please use the `mode=spell`. Here is the reference to that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-spell-check-api-v7-reference.

Please also provide `mkt` parameter in the query, if possible.

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks for reply. I've tested it with spell as well but it seems that it doesn't understand most of the stuff. I am promising a feature to a client. Is it really production ready?

Comment: BTW, mkt and setLang are present

Comment: This works for me: curl -X GET "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/spellcheck?text=ra%20pa%20sondag%20ka%20der%20komme%20ekssra&mkt=da-DK&mode=spell"

Comment: Thanks for the example Ronak. I see that your partial sentence work for me too. Is there any limitation on the number of words that we can send? It seems strange that it stops working after I add 2 more words. BTW, how come you haven't tested it with the complete sentence?

Comment: This is weird. I think you are using POST call, right?

Comment: Yes! I user post and that is very weird. :D BTW, doesn't it do the same thing on your machine when you try with the whole sentence?

Comment: It seems to be the same on other sentences as well for instance take a look at this sentence that I copied from the news today and changed skal to ska. It won't return anything for the whole sentence but it will work if you cut the part after dommer.  Ungdomskriminalitetsnævn%20ska%20bestå%20af%20en%20dommer%20og%20repræsentanter%20fra%20kommunernes%20sociale%20indsats

Comment: how can I grab someone in Microsoft for supporting this?

Comment: It seems the limit is 65 characters even though the specified length is 2048 chars for the URL. Proof mode supports longer text but it is not supported for the da-dk market. Also, not sure if you are using mkt=da-dk. If not pls correct that.

Comment: So to be able to work with this API in Danish, I can only send 65 chars? So if I'm suggesting stuff on UI, I have to take the last words up to 65 chars and call the API with it? But then how good it will understand the sentence if it only has a part in the middle of the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

A) The documentation still seems to say the limit is 65 characters, but mine varies and often cut-offs at ~50.

B) The preContextText and postContextText parameters doesn't seem to work, at least not with any of the tests I did that were very similar to those on the documentation page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-spell-check-api-v7-reference